# Can't connect to Selenium inside docker container in Python

Tags: python, docker, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to connect selenium inside docker container in Python.

I'm using M1 mac.
The steps I took were

1. `$ docker run -d -p 4444:4444 --shm-size="2g" selenium/standalone-chrome:4.0.0-rc-1-prerelease-20210804` (This command was referenced from https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/docker-selenium )
2. executing Python code below.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.desired_capabilities import DesiredCapabilities

driver = webdriver.Remote(
    command_executor="http://localhost:4444/wd/hub",
    desired_capabilities=DesiredCapabilities.CHROME
)

driver.get("https://stackoverflow.com/")
print(driver.title)
driver.quit()
```

It gives me error showing below.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/ren/Code/rarejob-tutor-checker/server/index.py", line 9, in <module>
    driver = webdriver.Remote(
  File "/Users/ren/.local/share/virtualenvs/rarejob-tutor-checker-yZ3a8Uiu/lib/python3.9/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 157, in __init__
    self.start_session(capabilities, browser_profile)
  File "/Users/ren/.local/share/virtualenvs/rarejob-tutor-checker-yZ3a8Uiu/lib/python3.9/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 252, in start_session
    response = self.execute(Command.NEW_SESSION, parameters)
  File "/Users/ren/.local/share/virtualenvs/rarejob-tutor-checker-yZ3a8Uiu/lib/python3.9/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 321, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "/Users/ren/.local/share/virtualenvs/rarejob-tutor-checker-yZ3a8Uiu/lib/python3.9/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 130, in check_response
    status = value["status"]
KeyError: 'status'
```

I have no idea why it's happening.

※ Note

1. I can connect to `http://localhost:4444/ui/index.html#/`[Screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SRCAi.png)
2. `curl` also works

```
$ curl http://localhost:4444/status
{
  "value": {
    "ready": true,
    "message": "Selenium Grid ready.",
    "nodes": [
      {
        "id": "af7033c1-aea3-46f3-9669-e8b1edb4922a",
        "uri": "http:\u002f\u002f4d3bede65cd7:4444",
        "maxSessions": 1,
        "osInfo": {
          "arch": "amd64",
          "name": "Linux",
          "version": "5.10.25-linuxkit"
        },
        "heartbeatPeriod": 60000,
        "availability": "UP",
        "version": "4.0.0-rc-1 (revision c498dad8c5)",
        "slots": [
          {
            "lastStarted": "2021-08-09T23:37:31.804771Z",
            "session": null,
            "id": {
              "hostId": "af7033c1-aea3-46f3-9669-e8b1edb4922a",
              "id": "eec094e6-ac6d-4fbc-907c-56d7d4cf8090"
            },
            "stereotype": {
              "browserName": "chrome",
              "browserVersion": "92.0",
              "platformName": "Linux",
              "se:vncEnabled": true
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: It looks less like your issue is with your Docker setup and connectivity etc, but that there was an issue with the response your Selenium code received, as it doesnt seem to include the status response. Have you checked the logs of the selenium container?

Comment: The error you get does not look like a docker error, but an error on your Docker host. Do you have selenium in the host too? `/Users/ren/Code/rarejob-tutor-checker/server/index.py` this is a path in the Mac host, not inside a docker container, which is supposed to be a Linux path.

Comment: @Abel Thank you for your comment!!
I also tried executing from inside docker container by using docker-compose and docker exec and typed below command.

`/sur/src/app# python3 server/index.py`
It gave me another error.

` raise RemoteDisconnected("Remote end closed connection without"
http.client.RemoteDisconnected: Remote end closed connection without response`

Answer (score 1):

It seems Selenium official image `selenium/standalone-chrome` doesn't work on M1 Mac OS because the code works properly when it's run on the Ubuntu OS.

Answer (score 0):

I recently encountered and resolved a similar issue which might help to you.

> > Go to your Docker Desktop setting >> Features in development >> Enable  Use Rosetta for x86/amd64 emulation on Apple Silicon

Before enable the option, while executing the `selenium/standalone-chrome` docker image on Mac M1, you might come across the following warning message:

> WARNING: The requested image's platform (linux/amd64) does not match the detected host platform (linux/arm64/v8) and no specific platform was requested

This issue can be addressed by referring to the information provided [here](https://collabnix.com/warning-the-requested-images-platform-linux-amd64-does-not-match-the-detected-host-platform-linux-arm64-v8/), If you have not enabled `Use Rosetta for x86/amd64 emulation on Apple Silicon` in your Docker Desktop for Mac, then you can find the container logs (`docker logs $YOUR_CONTAINER_ID`) which may yield the following error message after you start a new session:

> Error while creating session with the driver service. Stopping driver service: Could not start a new session. Response code 500. Message: unknown error: DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist

The error message with my Golang code like this:

> "message":"invalid session id: Unable to execute request for an existing session: Unable to find session with ID: \nBuild info: version: '4.10.0', revision: 'c14d967899'\nSystem info: os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '5.15.49-linuxkit-pr', java.version: '11.0.19'\nDriver info: driver.version: unknown"

In essence, this error occurs when there is a mismatch between the platform of the requested Docker image and the host platform. Enabling the 'Rosetta' option for emulation should mitigate this issue by allowing Docker to run images built for a different architecture.

I hope this helps in your scenario.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34749809)