# Selenium giving requested image's platform does not match the detected host platform (linux/arm64/v8)

Tags: docker, macos, selenium-webdriver, docker-compose, docker-registry

In the Docker Compose I'm using [`selenium/standalone-chrome`](https://hub.docker.com/r/selenium/standalone-chrome)

```
selenium:
    image: selenium/standalone-chrome
    container_name: selenium
    ports:
      - "4444:4444"
```

but I'm getting the following error

> selenium The requested image's platform (linux/amd64) does not match the detected host platform (linux/arm64/v8) and no specific platform was requested

How to fix that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [docker-selenium README](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/docker-selenium#experimental-mult-arch-aarch64armhfamd64-images)

> For experimental docker container images, which run on platforms such as the Mac M1 or Raspberry Pi, see the community driven repository hosted at [seleniumhq-community/docker-seleniarm](https://github.com/seleniumhq-community/docker-seleniarm). These images are built for three separate architectures: linux/arm64 (aarch64), linux/arm/v7 (armhf), and linux/amd64.

So, changed the image to [`seleniarm/standalone-chromium`](https://hub.docker.com/r/seleniarm/standalone-chromium)

```
selenium:
    image: seleniarm/standalone-chromium
    container_name: selenium
    ports:
      - "4444:4444"
```

Answer (score 0):

You also can use the image `selenium/standalone-chrome` on Mac M1, just try to follow this steps:

> > Go to your Docker Desktop settings >> Features in development >> Enable  Use Rosetta for x86/amd64 emulation on Apple Silicon

In essence, this error occurs when there is a mismatch between the platform of the requested Docker image and the host platform. Enabling the 'Rosetta' option for emulation should mitigate this issue by allowing Docker to run images built for a different architecture.

This solution was referenced from other questioin which I was [answered](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76772515/22289162).